# Открыть окно запущенного приложения

Tags: python, pyqt5

есть программа написанная на Python и PYQT5, есть небольшой интерфейс и при закрытии сворачивается в трей, вопрос, как при нажатии на .exe программы открывать её из трея, а не запускать новый экземпляр?
На примере с Telegram: получаю имя класса через стороннюю программу, Телеграм открывается скрытым, то есть окно есть на рабочем столе, но видны только его границы, а вот например с TeamViewer всё работает.
P.S. Если программа свёрнута в панель задач, то всё срабатывает нормально, а если она висит в трее, то происходит то что выше указал
P.S.S Код не мой, взят для примера с другого сайта
ОС Windows 10

```
    import win32gui
    import win32con

def windowEnumHandler(hwnd, top_windows):
top_windows.append((hwnd, win32gui.GetClassName(hwnd)))

def bringToFront(window_name):
top_windows = []
win32gui.EnumWindows(windowEnumHandler, top_windows)
for i in top_windows:
    # print(i[1])
    if window_name.lower() in i[1].lower():
        # print("found", window_name)
        win32gui.ShowWindow(i[0], win32con.SW_SHOWNORMAL)
        win32gui.SetForegroundWindow(i[0])
        break

  if __name__ == "__main__":
  winname = "Qt5153QWindowIcon"
  bringToFront(winname)
```

Comment: Вам видимо надо показать  [mcve], а также упомянуть какая у вас ОС.

Comment: Добавил пример и ОС.)

Comment: Решил проблему, скину сюда инструкцию